# Create Less.js Namespace to resolve conflicts between Style Sheets

Tags: less

I have two CSS Stylesheets (LineIcons and LineAwesome) that don't play nicely together.  I found some info [here](https://www.ryadel.com/en/css-namespaces-avoid-conflict-style-sheets-files/)that says I could use LESS to create namespaces to resolve such conflicts.  I installed Less.js, and created the style.less file, and tried to create the name space like this:

```
.LineIcons{
    @import 'LineIcons.less';
}

  <div class="panel-heading LineIcons" style="background-color:#bbc4cc; color:white">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-alt3" id="btnSave" style="font-weight:bold;color:#2A4351" onclick="saveCourse(@Model.CourseId)"><i class="lnir lnir-checkmark"></i>&nbsp;Save</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-alt3" data-dismiss="modal" style="font-weight:bold;color:#2A4351"><i class="lnir lnir-close"></i>&nbsp;Cancel</button>
</div>
```

As instructed in the online post, I included the namespace as a class in the div surrounding the icon class, but it is not working as my icons don't display anywhere.  I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: can you share the working demo what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @ShashankBhatt, thank you for trying to help, but if I could create a "working" example, I would not need any help.  I am trying to create namespaces for style sheets using Less.  I have been unable to figure out how to make that work.

Comment: Working demo doesn't necessarily mean the one without an issue. but it just just means combined html+css+ and its result like fiddle with your issue but practical not theoretical, so we can fix why it is not working for your case.